# Return value unaffected if Exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, return

If an Exception is thrown inside a method, is the return value left as it was before?

For example:

```
public int test(int a) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

and then:

```
a=2;
a=test(a);
```

...after catch...

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(a)); //a=?
```

Is a affected upon Exception? It seems logically not so(?) Can't find info on that though.
I neeed to be sure.

Comment: I'd *guess* that `a` is still 2, but why didn't you just try?

Comment: I did try, and it worked, but I need to be 100% sure that this is always the case.

Comment: If you passed an object as a parameter and modified its value before throwing an exception, then the object would still be modified.

Comment: @user2254314 It worked one time? So why the hell should it ever behave otherwise? What is the real problem?

Comment: Don't be rude. Is "it worked one time" a guarantee for something working all the time always? There could be some special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `a` will not be affected. It is declared in separate method than your `test()` method.

```
int a = 2;
try {
        a = obj.test(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));
    }
System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));
```

Both SOP will print 2.

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an exception, JAVA expects you to handle it. So the state of the application is kept intact. Thus the value of your variable remains unchanged.
Try,

```
 public int test(int a) {
        throw new Error();
    }
```

And see what happens :)